# Retrieve JSON Array element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My web service returned a JSON Array (ie. `[{"key":"value"}, {"key":"value2"}]`). In the array there are two items as you can see, which are separated with comma. I want to know how can I access the second item, and get the value of "key" for the second item.

I've tried:

```
var a = msg.d[1].key
```

With no success of course.

This is the returned string:

```
"[{"Code":"000000","Name":"Black","Id":9},{"Code":"BF2C2C","Name":"Red","Id":11}]"
```

The string was extracted using FireBug after watching the msg.d.
Need your help in solving this.

Comment: And what is `msg.d`? The JSON string?

Comment: @Felix: OP must be using ASP.NET which wraps JSON returns in `.d`

Comment: Yes it is, it represents the JSON string which the web service returns after JSON serialization in C#. I'm developing in ASP.NET and JQuery,

Comment: Show the surrounding code.  We need to know what `msg.d` is like Felix says and also whether you ever called `JSON.parse` or not. :-)

Comment: posted the returned string (just shorten it because it was much longer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
msg[1].key
```

Assuming that the name of that array is `msg`. I'm not sure what you are using `.d` for.

If `msg.d` is a string representing an array, use [`JSON.parse`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

```
JSON.parse(msg.d)[1].key
```

You can replace `key` with the key you are wanting, e.g. `Code`, `Name`, `Id`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected for me.

```
var msg = [{"key":"value"}, {"key":"value2"}];
var a = msg[1].key;
```

What is msg in the example above? Need more info to help.

Comment: Updates the post with the string response

Answer (score 0):

If `msg.d` is a *string* then you have to `eval` (uggh) or `parse` it before applying the array subscript.